# In FUSE, how do I get the information about the user and the process that is trying to read/write in the virtual file system?

Tags: filesystems, process, users, fuse

Say I created a FUSE filesystem called `foo` and mounted it at `/mnt/foo`.

If I have a user called `myuser` that is running `vi` to open a file in `/mnt/foo`, what FUSE methods or data structure contains the info about the user and process? I'd want the actual name of the user/group and process, or the RUID and PID.

I've been staring at [this](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a60144dbd1a893008d9112e949300eb77)
but I can't find the information I mention from the doxygen documentation.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here, but can be asked on [so]. Due to an artificial system restriction, it is no longer possible to migrate this question.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It happens to have a programming answer, but I believe that that shouldn’t make the question off-topic. Just looking at the question, it could have had an answer involving `/proc`, `/sys`, or something similar.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. This is a question involving code. Are users not allowed to ask questions about Unix utilities now?

Comment: The question explicitly asks about "FUSE methods or data structure[s]". Code, not utilities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the call to a fuse operation you can call `fuse_get_context()` to get the current calling user id, group id, process id, and umask in a [fuse_context Struct](http://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__context.html).

```
struct fuse_context {
        struct fuse *fuse;
        uid_t uid;
        gid_t gid;
        pid_t pid;
        void *private_data;
        mode_t umask;
};
```

Here's a [doc](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Egeoff/classes/hmc.cs135.201001/homework/fuse/fuse_doc.html) and [bsd](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/fuse_chan_fd.3?query=fuse_get_context%26sec=3) man page mentioning this function.

If you're using the lowlevel API you need to use `fuse_req_ctx` and pass in the `fuse_req_t` that was passed to the current function, see [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/fuse-devel/thread/e1ad867f0906231244o1433de76q2346b1db405e0627@mail.gmail.com/).  `fuse_req_ctx` [returns](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/include_2fuse__lowlevel_8h.html#ad1d1963190eb93ae5667d32d2b387ca1) a pointer to a [fuse_ctx struct](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__ctx.html) which has the `uid`, `gid`, `pid`, and `umask` of the invoking process.